# Get DISTINCT list of values within GroupBy sql

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have this Table

```
place  subplace   
A      x
A      x
B      x
A      y
B      y
A      y
A      z
```

When I do this query

```
SELECT place, count(distinct subplace) AS count_subplace
from  table 
GROUP BY place
```

I get result

```
place count_subplace
A     3
B     2
```

Now I want the list of the distinct elements rather than the count

I know we can use [string_agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

how can I call distinct and also groupby in it

I want result something like

```
place subplace_list
A     x,y,z
B     x,y
```

I have tried this which won't work

```
SELECT place, string_agg(distinct subplace,',') AS list_subplace
from  table 
GROUP BY place
```

Comment: Waht's your dbms?

Comment: Microsoft ,Azure data studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `string_agg` didn't support `distinct` inside.

You can try to use a subquery to `distinct` your result set.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT place, string_agg(subplace,',') AS list_subplace
from  (select distinct place,subplace from t) t1
GROUP BY place
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/05b50/5/0)**:

```
| place | list_subplace |
|-------|---------------|
|     A |         x,y,z |
|     B |           x,y |
```